# resize and see result in real time with js using resize() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    boxes = $('.heightHack');
    maxHeight = Math.max.apply( Math, boxes.map(function() {
        return $(this).height();
    }).get());
    boxes.height(maxHeight);
}
```

I used jquery onresize but I still need to refresh to see my result. Above is one of a demo for my height hack. My question is how to see instant or real time result along with users' event - resizing the windows.

Comment: If you put alert('onresize called'); inside your function do you get an alert when you resize?

Comment: @CrazyCasta yes.. it work but it isn't real time

Comment: You're saying that if you put alert at the top of that function it doesn't get called the instant that you resize your browser? What browser are you using?

Comment: @CrazyCasta the alert did trigger.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#resizeText').text('Width: ' + $(this).width() + ', Height: ' + $(this).height());
});
```

Do you mean this?
http://jsfiddle.net/sing0920/yKUyM/